# How can I extend the width of multiple columns with VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I recorded the following macro when I extended a single column. How can I extend 10 columns at once with this method?

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

    Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 20.14
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line of code will extend the width of 10 columns, A through J:

```
Columns("A:J").ColumnWidth = 20.14
```